# Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed" with Laravel 7 & SendGrid

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid

I am really struggling to figure this out. I have recently started a new Laravel 7 project and I am really struggling to get the SendGrid SMTP Relay to work correctly with the project.

I have looked all over StackOverflow, SendGrid Docs, and Google and I am still struggling to find a working solution.

**My .ENV file:**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD={{apikey from SendGrid}}
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@galacticdigital.co.za
```

**My config/mail.php file:**

```
'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.sendgrid.net'), 
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('apikey'),
            'password' => env('{{apikey from SendGrid}}'),
            'timeout' => null,
        ],
```

*Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed"* [image: Error Message Screenshot]

I am still getting this error even after running: 
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache

Is there please someone who can assist me in understanding what is going on here and how I can fix it. I am still busy learning Laravel and I am not the greatest at using it yet.

Comment: What have you tried to debug that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting ENV constants named `apikey` and `{{apikey from SendGrid}}`.

They are the values and not the names. So they are not found in the ENV file.

Correct the following lines:

```php
[   
    // .....
    'username' => env('apikey'),
    'password' => env('{{apikey from SendGrid}}'),
    // .....
]
```

To

```php
[   
    // .....
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    // .....
]
```

And make sure the API credentials in your ENV file are correct.